# How to check if a server port is open and connect from MFC

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

I need my CASyncSocket to check on a certain port on a host and connect to it as soon as it is available.

I am a java guy and is new to C++, I know that I can do error handling and try connecting again and again. But I am unsure how to implement this in MFC.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to check if a server port is open is to try and connect. Use the CAsyncSocket Connect function. You get a callback (OnConnect) letting you know whether the connection attempt worked or not. If it did not work use a timer (SetTimer/WM_TIMER) to try again.

There are several CAsyncSocket example apps in MSDN.

Comment: Well, That was exactly what I wanted! I fired connect and then put a timer to see if onConnect was called!